# Logarithm completeness axiom proof

Tags: real-analysis, logarithms, axioms

Consider the set
$$ S =  \{ r\in  \mathbb{Q}  \mid 2^r < 3 \}$$

Our professor wants us to show a few things,
1: that S is bounded from above.
2:  if  $  2^\delta < 3  $ there is an $n \in \mathbb{N} $ such that $2^{\delta + 1/n} < 3 $  where $\delta $ is the sup *S*
3: if  $  2^\delta > 3  $ there is an $n \in \mathbb{N} $ such that $2^{\delta - 1/n} > 3 $
4:  Show $2^\delta$ = 3
5: Show there exists a unique solution to $2^p =3$

I'm kind of stuck on where to start at the moment, I felt like using the idea that the set S could be rewritten as $$ S =  \{ m/n\in  \mathbb{Q}  \mid 2^m < 3^n \}$$
could definitely be useful.   I feel like if I could figure out the boundedness of the first part  I'd be good.   From there I'm kinda stumped, if y'all know any good logarithm proofs to look at or any ideas I'd love some help.

Comment: You forgot to mention that $\delta=\sup S$.

Comment: For part 1, note that $2^{r}$ increases as $r$ increases. Next two parts are a bit tricky and need more than algebraic thinking.

Comment: oh yah sorry.  I'll edit that in.

Comment: To show that $S$ is bounded from above, note that $S = \{ r \in \mathbb{Q} : r < \log_2(3) \}$.

Comment: Also $\delta$ is not necessarily rational (in fact it turns out to be irrational). So how do you define symbol $2^{\delta}$? Parts 2,3 depend on this crucial information. You textbook should provide this information before this exercise otherwise it is a pointless exercise.

Comment: we're not supposed to be relying on the concept of logarithm.  The point of this is to establish the existence of such a thing.  sorry I should have clarified that

Comment: Did my comments help? Let me know if you need more hints. I don't want to discourage you by giving a full blown solution. The question is neither too easy nor difficult.

Comment: Sorry If I'm missing how as r inceases $2^r$ increases points to a solution for the set to bounded from above.  I'm trying to work through it but am stumped at the moment

Comment: If $r>2$ then $2^r>2^2=4$ which is not the case if $r\in S$. Hence if $r\in S$ then $r\leq 2$. This was the easy part of the overall question.

Comment: oh god why am I dumb haha.  Yah that makes sense, analysis is the bane of my brain I swear.  Thanks for the help, I'll try to work through this

Comment: Don't feel sorry about yourself. Most of the mathematical education in school is designed to help you with symbols like $+, -, \times, /, =$ and analysis requires you to deal with $<, >$. You are not alone in the situation you are. Most students have problem figuring out trivial arguments about inequalities.

Comment: thanks for all the kind words and helpful ones too!  I think I have a lead for 2 and 3 here. Especially with 1 solved haha!